# PHP - including error

Tags: php, html, include

I have a php layout ("layout_head.php", "layout_foot.php") and layout_head.php is including some other pages ("navigation.php", "config.php"). I have these files:

```
/home/index.php
/home/layout_head.php
/home/layout_foot.php
/home/navigation.php
/home/admin/page.php
```

In navigation.php, I want to link to some other files in the same directory as index ("/home/"). But if I include ("../layout_head.php") in ("/home/admin/page.php"), it can't find for example navigation.php, because it isn't in the same directory. And I can't include the direct path ("http://www.website.de/layout_head.php") I hope you understand my problem.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use absolute paths to your included files. Also always use `require_once` instead of includes to prevent mistakes (includes generate `E_NOTICE`):

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home/layout_head.php');
```

Without suffix `once` you must control all the places where you include your files (no duplicate includes), but as I know it works faster than `require_once`.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
include ("layout_head.php");
```

as your navigation.php is in the home directory don't have to use ../

Comment: But, when I must use include("../layout_head.php"); in "/home/admin/page.php" and then it can't find the stylesheets defined in "layout_head.php"